# Client side Cache vs Cookie

Tags: asp.net, caching, httpcookie

What are the differences between `Client side cache` and `cookie`?
 I know `cookie` is a data structure.
 What about `client side cache`?
 Is this same with browser cache?

Comment: Cookie is comes under Clien Side caching friend  Please Refer this For know more about catching http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817647.aspx#cachingarchch2_usingaspnetclientside

Comment: Client side cache and cookie both are same.Both can be used to store page information on client side..

Answer (score 3):

Client side cache creates a local copy in the device. User can edit the file even the server is disconnected. But that local file will get updated when the server is reconnected

Answer (score 2):

If Client side cache and cookie ware the same then why we use both.
cookie is used to store some tiny information that you can use later,
some user options and etc.

the client side cache is made with other reason. it is made for device with slow internet connection. Sometimes this helps to store information that can be worked with when internet conection goes down, and when connection is up client device can upload data automaticly.
of course  you can force what kind of information you want to store.

It's my opinion extracted from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Although cookies and cache are two ways to store data on client's machine, they serve different purposes like:

- Cookie is used to store information to track different characteristics related to user, while cache is used to make the loading of web pages faster.
- Cookies expire after some time, but cache is kept in the client's machine until they are removed manually by the user.