# how to enable codeigniter browser cache

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I want to saved input field data in browser cache using Codeigniter

```
<input type="search" name="location" class="icon glass" placeholder="Enter Your Location" required>
```

This is my input field when a user inputs something and revisit this page another day this field data will be saved on browsers cache. how to enable this using Codeigniter 
I tried with `$this->output->cache($n);` But didn't understand with this. Can anyone please clarify me about Codeigniter caching to saved input field data in the browser cache.

Comment: What **exactly** are you looking for? CI is running on the server and can not put anything into the browser cache directly

Comment: in the input field when the user inputs something it will store in browser cache i just want this. I fixed it already using javascript local storage Thanks @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A web cache (or HTTP cache) is an information technology for the temporary storage (caching) of web documents, such as HTML pages and images, **to reduce bandwidth usage, server load, and perceived lag**. Cache is just a collection of data downloaded to help display a web page.([source](https://medium.com/techblogout/whats-the-difference-between-cache-and-cookies-53e7f4f094bb))

You can not retrive data from **browser cache**. What you need to use is **cookies** or **sessions**

You can find more about difference between cache and cookies here.

- [Client side Cache vs Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15065074/12731030)
- [Cache VS Session VS cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/553185/12731030)

You can use [Cookie Helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html) or [Session Library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html) to achieve you desired result.